# Material Design Spec - Leading for Same Font Style

Tags: android

I've been having a hard time understanding the Material Design guidelines for leading for text of the same style. I'm working on an app that displays a full RSS feed. The MD spec provides the following:

https://material.io/guidelines/style/typography.html#typography-line-height

These values for leading are huge.... My understanding is that these leading values should be applied only if different styles are shown close to each other. Is that correct?

If that's the case, then is there any guidance on how much leading I should use for text of the same style? The only thing that I see in the spec is this:

[image]

But it doesn't actually give me any hard dp values for what the leading should be.

Can anyone provide some guidance on this? How am I supposed to interpret the leading values that we're shown in the spec? Is there any recommendation for the leading that should be applied to text of the same style, or should I figure this out on my own?

Answer (score 1):

I think no matter whether two paragraphs are different in styles or not, you should use smaller leading value with larger paragraph spacing compared to a single paragraph.

In your circumstance, you may use `4A` for leading value with a `28dp` paragraph spacing if you have multiple paragraphs to display or `4B` for leading value if there's only one single paragraph.